# Android 2.1 SDK + ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator vs GC

Tags: java, android, concurrency, garbage-collection

I'm writing a game for android platform. I have bullets in ConcurrentHashMap and im checking for collisions. All works great but GC is running every 3-5 seconds, when checking with Allocation Tracker there are lots of allocations ( 90 % of them ), every with allocation size = 36 in java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator

Concurrency is the key because a lot of thing may happen to the bullets and normal arraylist throwed concurrent exception so i've switched to ConcurrentHashMap. How can i optimize it for speed and GC ?

```
for (IWeaponBullet xbullet : PlayerSystem.aEnemiesBulletsArray.values()) {
    //checking 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be calling this iteration too often. `values()` call is creating a collection and gives `new ValueIterator()` each time you start this for loop.

Can you cache these values maybe for longer period of times instead of executing the loop too often?

Comment: i'm afraid not, i'm checking in every frame for collision with another elements, there are a lot of objects that can modify this hashmap in one frame ;/